# Yii private common validation method

Tags: php, yii

In a Yii php project, I use a a custom validation:

```
public function rules() {   
    return array(
        array('nbC', 'cCustomValidation'),
}

public function cCustomValidation() {
    if ($this->nbC >= 1) {
        if (empty($this->c_attrA_1)) $this->addError('c_attrA_1', Yii::t('yii', '{attribute} cannot be blank.', array('{attribute}'=>$this->getAttributeLabel('c_attrA_1'))));
        if (empty($this->c_attrB_1)) $this->addError('c_attrB_1', Yii::t('yii', '{attribute} cannot be blank.', array('{attribute}'=>$this->getAttributeLabel('c_attrB_1'))));
        if (empty($this->c_attrC_1)) $this->addError('c_attrC_1', Yii::t('yii', '{attribute} cannot be blank.', array('{attribute}'=>$this->getAttributeLabel('c_attrC_1'))));
    }
}
```

I want to use a private function like this:

```
private function checkNotEmpty($attribute) {
    if (empty($attribute)) $this->addError(''.$attribute, Yii::t('yii', '{attribute} cannot be blank.', array('{attribute}'=>$this->getAttributeLabel($attribute))));
}
```

to call in cCustomValidation like this:

```
public function cCustomValidation() {
    if ($this->nbC >= 1) {
        checkNotEmpty($this->c_attrA_1);
        checkNotEmpty($this->c_attrB_1);
        checkNotEmpty($this->c_attrC_1);
    }
}
```

But my checkNotEmpty method doesn't work! Return nothing, no error but no validation or error added!
How can I write and call correct common private method for attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it as `$this->checkNotEmpty()` since it's a class method.